# Congruence Analytic Geometry Definition Question about Function where Its Input is a Set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Below I am going to rewrite a definition which I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)).

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $A, B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, $A$ and $B$ are said to be $\textbf{congruent}$ (Euclidean metric) iff there exists an isometry (a distance preserving function) $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(A)=B$.

> $\textbf{Question:}$ What does $f(A)=B$ mean here? $\underline{Specifically}$, how do we define $f(A)$? I know $f(A)$ has a very specific meaning in Topology which I can't remember.

Comment: $f(A) = \{f(a):a\in A\}$. This definition is not specific to topology, it's the same in all of mathematics.

Comment: @Wojowu You can write that in the answer too to get points (I know it will be a short answer, but that's exactly what I was looking for). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(A)$ is the *image* of the set $A$, which is the set of values which $f$ takes on elements of $A$. In symbols, $f(A)=\{f(a):a\in A\}$.

This definition is in no way specific to topology - it originates from set theory and is used all over the place in mathematics. Sometimes, to disambiguate between image of an element and an image of a subset, notation $f[A]$ is used instead.